A new API key and STILL openai.error.RateLimitError
I made a new account and a new API key on openai and STILL openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota. I made a program on python, that would access openai's api to answer my questions:
def chat(query):
    global chatStr
    print(chatStr)
    openai.api_key = apikey
    chatStr += f"Harry: {query}\n Jarvis: "
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        prompt= chatStr,
        temperature=0.7,
        max_tokens=256,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0
    )
    # todo: Wrap this inside of a  try catch block
    say(response["choices"][0]["text"])
    chatStr += f"{response['choices'][0]['text']}\n"
    return response["choices"][0]["text"]


def ai(prompt):
    openai.api_key = apikey
    text = f"OpenAI response for Prompt: {prompt} \n *************************\n\n"

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=0.7,
        max_tokens=256,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0
    )
    # todo: Wrap this inside of a  try catch block
    # print(response["choices"][0]["text"])
    text += response["choices"][0]["text"]
    if not os.path.exists("Openai"):
        os.mkdir("Openai")

    # with open(f"Openai/prompt- {random.randint(1, 2343434356)}", "w") as f:
    with open(f"Openai/{''.join(prompt.split('intelligence')[1:]).strip() }.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)

I wanted to use it but it shows
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\JarvisAI-YouTube-main\main.py", line 113, in 
chat(query)
File "F:\JarvisAI-YouTube-main\main.py", line 22, in chat
response = openai.Completion.create(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\completion.py", line 25, in create
return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
self._interpret_response_line(
File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
